# Windows iot core 10 build 16299 serial stopped working

Tags: uwp, serial-port, arduino-uno, uart, windows-10-iot-core

I have project where Rpi2 Iot Core 10 talks with Arduino using serial interface:

```
string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
var selectedPort = dis.Where(t => t.Name == "Genuino Uno").First();          
serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(selectedPort.Id);
```

Serial capability is defined in Package.appxmanifest:

```
<Capabilities>
<Capability Name="internetClient" />
<DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
  <Device Id="any">
    <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
  </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

This used to work in previous builds, but stopped working recently. I am using build 16299 at the moment.

1) What has changed?
2) Where can I download/get previous builds?

The code is based on this example: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/serialuart

Answer (score 0):

> 1)What has changed?

We can get the information about the new features on 16299 from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/release-notes/commercial/fallcreatorsupdate#whats-new-in-fall-creators-update).It seems that there are no changes about Serial device connection/communication on 16299. As see your code, I think you need to check the name of SerialDevice is *"Genuino Uno"*,if not, there will be an exception thrown at the next line, because *selectedPort* is null:

```
serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(selectedPort.Id);
```

> 2)Where can I download/get previous builds?

What previous build did you mean? Build 15063 or else? The following url is for downloading version 15063.Other build you can search from internet.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55031

Comment: 1) It might be some older build between the one that worked and this new one. I have to investigate, thanks.

I was thinking the change might have something to do with this?:

"On Windows 10 IoT Enterprise, we've enabled access to industry standard buses like GPIO, I2C, SPI, and UART from user mode through the Windows.Devices APIs."


The serial device is same and it used to work with that name. Now there is one another usb device found, but that doesn't work with previous settings either.

2) Thanks, I will try that out.